# While starting ember server I'm getting this error like SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier async postBuild()

Tags: ember.js

While starting ember server I'm getting this error
What could be the reason for this error?

```
Unexpected identifier
/Users/chraju/Desktop/sites/blog-front-end/node_modules/ember-cli-typescript/js/addon.js:47
    async postBuild() {
          ^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:549:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:586:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:494:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:453:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:445:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:504:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/chraju/Desktop/sites/blog-front-end/node_modules/ember-cli-typescript/index.js:9:20)
```

Comment: What node version are you using?

Comment: I'm using node v6.17.0

Comment: Your node version seems to be fully outdated. Support for it has long ended. Both from node itself as well as from Ember CLI TypeScript. I would recommend to upgrade to a recent node version.

Comment: What if I should not update node?

Comment: It worked fine till yesterday. Today suddenly stopped working.

Comment: I guess you either updated dependencies or downgraded your node version if it worked fine before. If you can't upgrade your node version you must downgrade ember CLI typescript to a version which supports such an old node version. But expect other dependencies to also not support such an old node version in recent releases. E.g. ember itself.

Comment: Do you use any strategy to lock down the exact versions of your dependencies? E.g. by `yarn.lock` or `package-lock.json`? It seems as if your dependency versions are changing if you are touching the environment. Upgrading the node version installed on your computed should not change any version of your project's dependencies. If they are, you don't lock down your dependency versions or run `yarn upgrade` / `npm update` in parallel. You end up with two moving targets, which complicates things.

Comment: working fine after updating. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

update node

> nvm install 8.11.1

use the updated version

> nvm use 8.11.1

in package.json update ember-cli version

**"ember-cli": "2.13.3"**

remove node module and run

> rm -rf node_modules

> npm install

> ember s

working fine now